# Request for better 'belongs on' suggestions for flagging as off topic

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, migration

When you try to flag a post as off-topic, the only option you get is to suggest to migrate is to meta.

Can I suggest we start to have some more options here, for example

- literature.stackexchange.com
- scifi.stackexchange.com

These are suggested as it is probably going to be common for people to ask about plot points that might be better addressed in the story the movie was adapted from.

I ask this as it seems more rude to suggest 'this is off topic' whereas 'this would be better on xx' seems a lot more constructive.

Comment: In related news: please don't migrate crap away. Just saying...

Comment: @IvoFlipse hopefully we should be closing crap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think a question would fare better on a different site, but that it is not actually on-topic here, then you this is not sufficient reason to migrate the question. If the question isn't getting good answers here, and it's also on-topic on another site, then you may suggest to the asker that *they* flag for migration.

**Do not tell the asker to repost, tell them to flag for migration.**

If, as the asker, you regret asking here and wish you'd asked on some other site, flag your question (or grab a moderator's attention however you like, for example in chat).

The usual *modus operandi* for a moderator in such cases is that they'll ask a moderator of the target site to confirm that the question is welcome on the target site.

Answer (score 4):

Migrations in private beta are not possible as no one knows whether the site will survive or not.

Once the site passes into public beta I am sure these options will be available (the developers would have already made the suitable choice to put them in the correct sites for migration when public beta time is ready)

The point for now is to show what belongs and does not belong in scope and to edit the FAQ scope as such.

Comment: I wondered whether it was a private beta issue - but wanted to make the suggestion to 'the powers' that these sites be included.  I guess the 'feature request' tag is read by some moderators.

Comment: The public beta may start tomorrow.  Computational Science went public today.  They have *similar* stats to Movies, the main difference is a lower answer rate on our site.

Comment: @iandotkelly Oh ok I see that now. Based on those stats it would seem that way. Hopefully the site launches tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

> I ask this as it seems more rude to suggest 'this is off topic' whereas 'this would be better on xx' seems a lot more constructive.

I'm going to have to take a stab at this to get people out of a certain mindset. **Migration is not for putting things where they might fit "better"**. You should be considering migration only if the question is *off-topic* for the current site - that's why it's a subset of the off-topic close reason to begin with. If it is a valid question for the current site, then it is not wrong for it to stay here. Our tools for migration are designed to handle the case where it *is* wrong to stick around.

---

To address the actual flag concern, [Alonzo has the right of why we don't open up migration paths this early](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/96/14). However, **you can always just use a custom flag to say "This belongs on this other site"**. This will deliver the same message you were wanting to in the first place, and has the freedom of letting you specify any weird site in the event of particularly unusual scenarios.

Comment: I don't disagree - I didn't mean to imply that you should migrate purely to make a better fit, it has to be off-topic first